# Localization native development region does not change the app language

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I am building an app which I only want it to be in Swedish. 
Based on many questions in SO I set the `Localication native development region` to `Sweden`. 
I set this in the app-info.plist.

But this does not seem to work. The app and the systemButtons are always displayed in English. 
SHould i do something else to make it work?

Is this value overridden somewhere else? (I am mainly concerned about UITableView delete to a translated version of 'delete' button)

Your help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ableView:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3atitleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath%3a) to force the name of the delete in the table view.